# Send Notification ID through to activity for each notfication

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I am seriously confused now, I have been reading several SE examples and they all seem to be doing slightly different things.

What i want to do: Is have a single Activity called `NotificationActivity`, when I click on a notification it must open that activity and provide the activity with a `DeviceId`. I don't want to override or update any pending activities. Each activity should be its own intent.

There should only be once instance of `NotificationActivity`.

here is the code I have so far:

MyGcmListenerService:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    //ADD My Extras
    intent.putExtra(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_DEVICE_ID, content.DeviceId);
    intent.putExtra(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_DEVICE_TYPE_ID, content.DeviceTypeId);
    intent.putExtra(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_DEVICE_NAME, content.DeviceName);
    //
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);   

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(content.DeviceName)
            .setContentText("Notification")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(ingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setGroup("Mi:" + content.DeviceId)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NotificationID++, notificationBuilder.build());
```

and my NotificationActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

    deviceId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_DEVICE_ID, -1);
    deviceName = getIntent().getExtras().getString(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_DEVICE_NAME, "");
    deviceTypeId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_DEVICE_TYPE_ID, 0);
```

What am I missing here/ I think I am getting mixed up with all the different flags and launcher types.

If there is already an `NotificationActivty` in memory, I want to close it and open a new one with the latest intent. If there are 3 notifications on the users phones, and they click on all three. it must open the NotificationActivty for the last clicked Notification.

There must be an issue with my pending intent?

Answer (score 1):

In NotificationActivity, you collect int or long value using following code i.e.

```
notificationID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_NOTIFICATIONID, 0);
```

then please pass a proper value with putExtra() i.e. if collect int then pass `Integer.parseInt(content.DeviceId)` or collect long then pass `Long.parseLong(content.DeviceId)`
hope it's helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

In Notification class add this line

```
intent.putExtra(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_NOTIFICATIONID, NotificationID);
```

In NotificationActivity

```
notificationID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_NOTIFICATIONID, 0);
```

Comment: How is that different from what I have done? You changed `Long` to `Int`? My `deviceId` is a long?

Comment: u change ur datatype according to ur requirement...   u r not intent notification id....

Comment: So what are you changing? You are suggesting exactly what I am doing?

Comment: Hi Narendra. I notice you're adding a request for votes to a good number of your questions. Please don't do this - we prefer people to receive votes naturally rather than spoiling posts to get them. It is OK to remind people in comments if they may not know how upvoting and acceptance works, but don't overdo it!